# Computing effect size (d) for lmer() in R

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, effect-size, cohens-d

I have selected to compute the Cohen's d effect size for the fixed effects of my linear mixed model. However, it's a little unclear why I'm getting the results I am. First, I am using the method presented by Westfall 2014. Here is an example of the formula:

[image]

This is based on the lmer() output. So here is an example of how it was computed in the article:

[image]

So in this example, they compute it this way:

d = (16.029)/(sqrt(10032.34+27.89+1900.12+19.88+22128.15)) = 0.0868

I am using this method for my model data to compute the d for two different models.

1. `model<- lmer(respTime ~ task*objectCount+ (1| Subject),data = dt, control=lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))`

[image]

2. `mode2<- lmer(respTime ~ task*featureClutter+ (1| Subject),data = dt, control=lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))`

[image]

The difference between the two types of models are the two different clutter metrics being used. Both are numeric values. The task variable consist of 2 types of tasks (two levels). Based on the Westfall (2014) method for computing effect sizes for each fixed effect I get the below d values:

Model 1: task d = 0.70 and ObjectClutter d = 0.035
Model 2: task d = 0.68 and featureClutter d = 0.34

If you use the estimate and the variances, you will see that the computations do result in these d values.

Is the difference between the clutter effect sizes attributed to the fact that the estimates for those fixed effects are so different? Is using this method for computing d a viable option? I realize there is also a R function that computes d 'scores', specifically lme.dscore(). But this function gives very different d values, which is confusing.

Note: I realize this post may elicit a debate/conversation about what type of effect size to use. I am interested in addressing this question based on Cohen's d effect size.